# Give different permission to different user in SFTP in ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, permissions, ubuntu-14.04, sftp

I have setup SFTP refereed from [here](https://bensmann.no/restrict-sftp-users-to-home-folder/) and I have directory structure like following.

[image]

Now in my case, there are multiple users who can access files as per their privileges, as follow.

1. Super admin - full access to all dir
2. Admin - admin can access some dir, example one+two

Issue is, I am not able to set multiple permission to one directory, for example,

If I set permission for super-admin group 770, and now I want to set permission to /Security/one dir, I have to use chgrp ([reference](https://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu)), then dir lost its super admin privileges.

can some please help out here.

Comment: I am not really sure about the how, but I know most recent Linux systems allow you to use ACLs instead of Unix permissions. This allows for way more flexible setting of permissions and access restrictions on files and folders. I'll let people who know write actual answers though.

Comment: thank you @nathan. anyway. well I have never user ACL. but I can try that for sure, its not an issue.

Comment: @NathanShiraini can you please send me some reference for ACL using that I can fulfill my objective?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs , https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=acl and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list

Comment: @NathanShiraini I was trying to manage it using ACL yesterday, but there were 2 issue, if I give rw permission to user he is not able to list from directories, and if I give him rwx permission then it is able to listing but now they have full permission. they are able to make new directories their. I don't understand why...:(

Comment: IIRC read access to a *directory* is what is required to list its content, it may be different when using ACL. Try to see if there is a "list files" permission on directories, or something like that.