# Give a group write permission to a folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, user-groups

I need help understanding how giving write permission to a group, works in Ubuntu. I am logged in as root and have a `www-data:www-data` and `ftpuser:ftpuser` (`user:group`). I add the `ftpuser` into the `www-data` group using:

```
usermod -a -G www-data ftpuser
```

Now my `www-data` group has two users.

I then make the group `www-data`, owner of the folder `/var/www` using:

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/www
```

Still i have no write ability to the folder by a group member (though the group owns it) unless i give write permissions to the group. Now according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu?newreg=5920d86ee51a4f8ca12cef7bfd055aba) best answer i also need to set the permissions to the directory using `sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/the/directory` and this is what confuses me.

If a user is the owner of a directory why can't he write to it?
Can a user of a group give the group write permissions to a folder owned by the group himself?
Where is the group defined in the command `sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/the/directory` ? Won't this give recursive permissions to all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> though the group owns it

No, group does not own a file in a sense that the permissions for `owner` apply. Owner permissions apply only to owner - the user; and group permissions apply to the assigned group.

> If a user is the owner of a directory why can't he write to it?

He can, except that `ftpuser` in your case is not the owner.

Most likely, because you don't say it explicitly: `root` or `www-data` is the owner `/var/www` of the file, and `ftpuser` is a member of the group `www-data`.

Even if the user `www-data` and the group `www-data` have the same name, they are different entities for the operating system.

> Can a user of a group give the group write permissions to a folder owned by the group himself?

Again: folder is not owned by a group. If the group has write-permission, any member of the group can change the permissions to the object.

> Where is the group defined in the command `sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/the/directory`

The second `7` refers to the group permissions (`7` is a combination of `read`, `write`, and `execute`).

> Won't this give recursive permissions to all users?

It will assign (recursively):

- `read`, `write`, and `execute` for the owner (first `7`)
- `read`, `write`, and `execute` for the group (second `7`)
- no permissions for other users (last `0`)

Answer (score 0):

## Directory shared by group with write permissions for existing files

All users should be a members of a group www-data. You can add them using

`usermod -a -G www-data user1
usermod -a -G www-data user2
...`

Giving a group www-data a write permission to a folder and all containing files could be achieved with the series of commands:

`chgrp -R www-data /var/www
chmod -R g+ws /var/www`

All new files and directories will have assigned group www-data and will be writable by member of the group.

## Permissions for new files

Default umask on most Linux systems is 022 meaning if user1 creates a file or directory under /var/www that file becomes "editable" only by user1, but readable by group www-data.

**If this is expected behavior you should stop here.**

## Directory shared by group with write permission

You should verify whether extended ACL are enabled on your system. You may look at /etc/fstab and look for something like this:

`/dev/sda5  /  ext4  acl,.....`

Having this checked you need to provide an extended ACL parameters for directories.

You will add ACL to allow new files created under /var/www folder to be also writable ty www-data group using this command:

`setfacl -R -b -k -d -m g:www-data:rwx --mask $2`

In this senario if a user1 creates a file or folder under /var/www user2 will be able to write/delete.

Every new file or directory will have permissions rw-rw-???. Question marks will be something that you set for the others.

## How to verify permissions

Use this command:

`getfacl /var/www`

The output should be something like this:

`# file: /var/www
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---`

Default permissions for folder /var/www are: drwxrws---

Comment: Why are you including **`s`** in ``chmod -R g+ws``?  Did you mean ``chmod -R g+wx``?