# Ubuntu www-data group permission on newly created folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have 2 user `userA and www-data` in group `www-data`, on my web server I have php script that create folder and file

```
<?php
mkdir('dynamicDir');
file_put_contents('dynamicDir/z.txt', 'test');
```

output permission

```
drwxr-sr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Aug 19 23:33 dynamicDir
```

but when I run python script on shell using user `userA`

```
import os
os.remove('dynamicDir/z.txt')
```

I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.remove('dynamicDir/z.txt')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dynamicDir/z.txt'
```

for already created folder/file I can use `chmod -R g+rwx mydir/parentOfMyDir` but how for dynamic directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions:

1. change `php-fpm` user in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

from

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

to

```
user = userA
group = www-data
```

change permission for `web root` and `session` (if you have) folder

```
chown -R userA:www-data /var/www/html
chown -R userA:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions
```

2. using `setfacl`, [read more](https://superuser.com/a/1368581/733275)